# Homebrew installation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, osx-mavericks, homebrew, failed-installation

I downloaded Homebrew from the git source (`ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"`) but when I write `brew -v` or `brew doctor` I get this error:

```
/usr/local/bin/brew: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

/usr/local/bin/brew: line 23: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: Undefined error: 0
```

I have erased the ruby 1.8 version in my file due to having 2.0 version. May the error occurs because of that? or any other specific reason?

Comment: Moral of the story: *never* delete files in `/System/Library` or `/usr` (other than `/usr/local`).  They are part of OS X and managed by Apple. You need to restore the deleted `ruby` file to have a fully functional OS X system.

Comment: @NedDeily is right, many things depend on the system installation of ruby. maybe you can restore it from a timemachine backup? worst case: reinstall mac os x.

Answer (score 0):

> I have erased the ruby 1.8 version in my file due to having 2.0 version. May the error occurs because of that?

Yeah, that's why. The Homebrew script uses the version of Ruby that ships with OS X, so it's always using a known version. You shouldn't delete frameworks that ship with OS X.

Comment: i have Ruby 2.0 as default. I had installed ruby 1.8 due to wrong advice. And then i erased it. But how can I fix this homebrew problem? That is what i want to do now.